# Move the records per page next to pagination in datatables

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable

I'm using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net), with their example i was able to build tables nicely. But the problem is i don't seem to understand how to move the "`records per page`" element, which is a "`span6`" class of bootstrap. i do get the point that it's actually javascript which is doing this, need some help on this. Here is the [LINK](http://www.datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/) for the example i'm using.

Answer (score 2):

This is the div you are taking about in that page

```
<div class="span6">
    <div id="example_length" class="dataTables_length">
        <label>
            <select size="1" name="example_length" aria-controls="example">
                <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>records per page</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just copy this to other location and modify the css accordingly.

To modify the DOM using Javascript. 
http://woork.blogspot.in/2007/10/how-to-change-text-using-javascript.html

Comment: Hey, yup this is exactly what i'm worried about its not in my HTML page, its coming from Javascript.

Comment: You can give the div tag an id... and the get the whole DOM using Javascript, and append it another Javascript DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page in their documentation... [DataTables dynamic language](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html). It doesn't give the best explanations of how to move things but it's a good place to start experimenting. I was able to hide or change the "records per page" text and I would image there is a way to move it as well.

The preamble on that page says "Changing the language information displayed by DataTables is as simple as passing in a language object to the dataTable constructor. The example above shows a different set of English language definitions to be used, rather than the defaults."

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page"
}
```

should give you a place to start.